# Pressure and Temperature in a few-body system

Tags: thermodynamics

This question is very much related to [this other one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/201910/non-extensivity-in-a-few-body-system), and the introduction is the same.

If we want to define intensive properties for few-body systems it is not straightforward. I am referring specifically to a classical system, where the pair interactions are enough to confine it, i.e. all particles are within a certain volume without the intervention of external forces. And the pair interactions are assumed to be repulsive at certain characteristic separation and attractive at a larger characteristic separation.

The problem is evident from comparing with the ideal gas model: all movement is free, and related to temperature, and all pressure is related to the interaction in the walls containing the system.

Hence for a self-confined system like the one mentioned above, there is no interaction in the frontier, and there is not well defined frontier to the system. And all movement inside the volume involves interaction with other particles.

So under these conditions: **What definition of temperature and pressure are used, which references talk about this?**

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem defining intensive quantities in the grand canonical ensemble, where the intensive quantities appear as the parameters defining the ensemble. Indeed, this is the ensemble closest to the application. For a treatment of (classical or quantum) thermodynamics solely in terms of the grand canonical ensemble see Part II of my book [Classical and Quantum Mechanics via Lie algebras](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/0810.1019).

The identification with experiment, however, requires establishing equilibrium with the measurement instrument, hence corresponding boundary conditions.